# error: cannot access SaslException class file for javax.security.sasl.SaslException not found

Tags: java, android, xmpp, smack

I want to use the latest release of smack 4.0.0 in my project for xmpp with android studio 0.6.0,the code as below:

```
    try{
        ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("wooxonline.com",4000);
        XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
        connection.connect();
        connection.login("cliff","cliff123");
    }
    catch (SmackException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (java.io.IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (XMPPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i(TAG, "login failed!");
    }
```

this almost like sample with the smack sample code,but I have a compile issue that can't be solved as below trace info:

```
Error:(58, 29) error: cannot access SaslException
class file for javax.security.sasl.SaslException not found
```

I'm stuck here and anyone can help to have a look?

Comment: facing same problem... anybody got solution?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. This is the appropriate import sentence:

`import org.apache.harmony.javax.security.sasl.SaslException;`

Answer (score 0):

According to the official forum "Smack does not work on Android. You need aSmack." So you should try to change the library to [ASmack](https://github.com/flowdalic/asmack).

You can use maven to get the jar or download it from [here](http://asmack.freakempire.de/)

Reference:https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/52833